# Permutations of Hopf algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, hopf-algebras

Let $A$ be a connected finite dimensional Hopf algebra. Then this algebra is selfinjective and thus there is a permutation $\pi$ with $soc(P_i)=top(P_{\pi(i)})$ for the indecomposable projective $A$-modules $P_i$.

Can any permutation appear as such a permutation associated to a Hopf algebra and if yes, is there an explicit example?

And if no, which permutations can appear?

Comment: Do you really want $A$ to be connected? At least in characteristic zero, if $A$ is connected and finite dimensional, then it is in fact 1-dimensional (because $Ext_{A^*}(k,k)=0$).

Comment: Yes I want it to be connected. of course in characteristic nonzero such a thing can not happen, see for example group algebras.

Comment: Can you give some examples for such? The only one I can think of is indeed the dual of a group algebra, which is semisimple, and there the permutation $\pi$ is trivial.

Comment: In any case, notice that if we denote by $\tau$ the duality for simple representations, then we easily get that $(\pi\tau)^2 =Id$. This show that $\langle \pi,\tau\rangle$ is a dihedral group. Unfortunately, this still does not give an answer to your question.

Comment: A connected  Nakayama algebra with n simples and Loewy length L, which is zero mod $n$ gives an example with non-trivial permutation. Most non-symmetric Hopf algebras will give nontrivial examples. (group algebras are symmetric so the permutation is the identity)